# How to add logging for sequelize update

Tags: javascript, mysql, logging, sequelize.js

In my project `sequelize` logging is disabled, but I want active logging in the exact query.

How can I do that?

```
TableModel.update(
    {counter: 0},
    {where: {
        id: itm.i
    }},
    ).then((res) =>{
        console.log('res',res);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('update error : ', e);
    });
```

I know how I can do it in findall query like this:

```
TableModel.findAll({where: {...}, logging: console.log})
```

but in the update, I can't find any solution.

**sequelize version: 5.21**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Was so easy, you need to just add `logging:true` in the sequelize options.

```
TableModel.update(
    {counter: 0},
    {
        where: {
            id: itm.i
        },
        logging:true
    }
    ).then((res) =>{
        console.log('res',res);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('update error : ', e);
    });
```