# How to enable sequelize logging for one table

Tags: javascript, mysql, logging, sequelize.js

I want to see all queries of specific table.

Not for all queries like:

[Enable logging for all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21427501/5902688)

Or one specific query like:

[Enable logging for update query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59481110/5902688)

Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable logging for specific table by sync options.

```
TableModel.sync({ logging: console.log });
```

And if you want disable it just set it to `false`.

```
TableModel.sync({ logging: false });
```